# How to differ a string object's real properties from its content?

Tags: javascript, object

Consider the following code:

```
var str = new String("a");
str["prop"] = "b";
str[1] = "c";

for (var i in str)
{
    if (str.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log(i + " = " + str[i]);
}
```

The output will be:

```
1 = c
0 = a
prop = b
a
```

So how can I determine that "b" and "c" are "real" properties (i.e. not part of the actual string) while "a" is part of that string?

EDIT: code was not complete

Comment: From where the hell do you get `1 = c`?

Comment: just get the integer ordered(from 0) keys.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to ad the "c" bit of code

Comment: Amine, how do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "parts of the string" are non-writable properties with a numeric name smaller than the length of the string.

```
for (var i in str) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(str, i)) continue;
    if (/0|[1-9]\d+/.test(i) && +i<str.length) continue;
    // or String(i>>>0)===i && …

    console.log(i + " = " + JSON.stringify(str[i]));
}

// Output:
1 = "c"
prop = "b"
```